# Given 4 numbers generate all the combinations using basic operators (+, -, *,/ and parentheses)such that the result is 24

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Given a list of 4 integers, I have to find out all the combinations of them using  basic math operators and parentheses such that it evaluates to 24. For example if the 4 numbers are 1,2,3,4 the expressions 1*2*3*4 or (4+2)*(3+1) can evaluate to 24. I found the algorithm [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/solve24game/) but I don't fully understand it to implement the program.

Simple recursion can give me the combinations which don't include parentheses. I want to understand how to solve it where parentheses are involved.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @RamanMishra I can't figure out how to approach this problem. I can go with recursion but I am not sure how to use parentheses in this problem.

Comment: With brute force you can do that (parentheses all the same just check if the expression is valid). What is you time completely constraints?

Comment: @dWinder there aren't any time constraints specified.

Comment: Then you may try https://stackoverflow.com/a/50249013/6487675 (with `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(`, `)`) and check with the `eval` if the expression is valid and its result (wrap with `try-catch`)

Comment: This is the "math 24" problem, also keyed as "target value".  Try searching on those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the 'parenthesis-problem' you could think of your problem as follows:

"Create all [Binary Expression Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree)s  containing the operators + - * / and the given numbers 1,2,3,4. The evaluated expression must be 24."

The parenthesis result from the evaluation-order implicit represented in the tree.

So simply create all possible trees, evaluate them to check if the result is 24 and than print the valid ones including the parenthesis (either by putting parenthesis around every operation, or only if evaluation-order needs them)

Comment: That's what I needed. I was unaware of binary expression trees. Will try it when I have time and post the code.

Answer (score 2):

The task is easy if we don't have parenthesis: all we have to do is to enumerate all the operations. Assuming we have `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`:

```
   1 + 2 + 3 + 4
   1 + 2 + 3 - 4
   1 + 2 + 3 * 4
   1 + 2 + 3 / 4
   1 + 2 - 3 + 4 
   1 + 2 - 3 - 4 
   1 + 2 - 3 * 4  
   1 + 2 - 3 / 4  
   1 + 2 * 3 + 4  
   ...
   1 / 2 / 3 + 4  
   1 / 2 / 3 - 4 
   1 / 2 / 3 * 4
   1 / 2 / 3 / 4
```

We have just `4 ** 3 = 64` formulae in total. Let's add *parenthesis*. We can use them in `3! == 6` ways (let `^` be an operaion any of `+, -, *`):

```
   (((1 ^ 2) ^ 3) ^ 4)    // order of operations: 1, 2, 3
    ((1 ^ 2) ^ (3 ^ 4))   // -/-                  1, 3, 2 
    ((1 ^ (2 ^ 3)) ^ 4)   // -/-                  2, 1, 3 
     (1 ^ ((2 ^ 3) ^ 4))  // -/-                  2, 3, 1 
    ((1 ^ 2) ^ (3 ^ 4))   // -/-                  3, 1, 2 
     (1 ^ (2 ^ (3 ^ 4)))  // -/-                  3, 2, 1
```

Now we have `64 * 6 == 384` formulae to test.

Finally, we can shuffle numbers (in `4! == 24` ways):

```
  1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4
  1 ^ 2 ^ 4 ^ 3
  1 ^ 3 ^ 2 ^ 4 
  1 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 2  
  ...
  4 ^ 3 ^ 2 ^ 1
```

And we have `24 * 384 == 9216` formulae to execute, which can be done by *brute force* (with `eval` or it's equivalent)

**Pseudo code:**

```
 # All possible arguments order
 for (permutationIndex in 0..23) {
   int[] numbers = Permutation({1, 2, 3, 4}, permutationIndex);  

   # All possible operations
   foreach (op1 in {"+", "-", "*", "/"})
     foreach (op2 in {"+", "-", "*", "/"}) 
       foreach (op3 in {"+", "-", "*", "/"}) {
         # All possible parenthesis 
         formulae[] = {
           "(((numbers[0] op1 numbers[1]) op2 numbers[2]) op3 numbers[3])",            
           "((numbers[0] op1 numbers[1]) op2 (numbers[2] op3 numbers[3]))",
           "((numbers[0] op1 (numbers[1] op2 numbers[2])) op3 numbers[3])", 
           "(numbers[0] op1 ((numbers[1] op2 numbers[2]) op3 numbers[3]))",
           "((numbers[0] op1 numbers[1]) op2 (numbers[2] op3 numbers[3]))", 
           "(numbers[0] op1 (numbers[1] op2 (numbers[2] op3 numbers[3])))",
         }

         foreach (formula in formulae)
           if (eval(formula) == 24)
             Write(formula); 
       }   
   }
```

Comment: This is a nice approach but the order of the integers can change so you have to make 4! = 24 * 162 tries. There might be some optimizations cause '+'  and '*' are interchangeable. Plus how would you approach it when the size of integers isn't fixed to 4?